# What should I install to fix this error in Moovida Media Center?

Tags: codecs

I am trying to watch MTS files, but there is an error when I try to play them. It tells me to install subpicture x-pgs, but I can't find this in the Ubuntu Software Centre

I have installed `ubuntu-restricted-extras` but I the error persists.

The screenshot below shows the error dialog (in Polish): http://ubuntuone.com/25GB5xbWOfGQEyVM9aWBd8

Which roughly translates to:

*"Unfortunately Moovida selected media can reproduce only partially. Managed to get the following technical information, which can help in ozwiazaniu problem:*

*Installing these codecs should allow playback: subpicture decoder / x-pgs"*

Answer (score 2):

The company behind the [moovida software is Fluendo](http://www.fluendo.com/faq/#) - naturally they would recommend that you purchase their *Fluendo Complete Codec Pack* - this is available in the software center.  If you do this, at least you will get support from the company itself.

The alternative is to investigate using software such as Handbrake or WinFF to convert the MTS files to a format that you have a codec for & that is supported by Moovida - for example:

> Moovida supports most commonly used file formats. A partial list of
>   codecs and file containers includes: mpeg/mpg, mpeg1, mpeg2, vp6,
>   svq3, mpeg4, h264, h263, theora, wmv, avi, asf, mov, ogg,
>   matroska(mkv), flv, mp3, ac3, aac, dts, vorbis, flac, wma.

Comment: Ubuntu 11.10 I have install restricted extras but this not change notching